# Connecting to localhost using Python-flask on Google Colab?

Tags: python, web-services, flask, google-colaboratory

I am a newcomer to flask. I cannot access localhost:5000 or 127.0.0.1:5000 . I am using flask . I have tried many solutions but none of them worked for me.
Here's the code

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return ('Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

I get this

```
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

when i go to localhost:5000 or 127.0.0.1:5000 ,  i get

> 127.0.0.1 refused to connect** or **localhost refused to connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run your app like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

This also makes the server [externally visible](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#public-server). If the IP address of the machine is `192.168.X.X` then, from the same network you can access it in 5000 port.

It could also be an issue with the firewall, in which case, do the following:

```
sudo ufw allow 5000
```

**Edit:**

Since you are running on Google Colab and not on your local system. The running steps would vary.

Do note that

> Google Colab provides a VM(virtual machine) so we cannot access the localhost(all it does it route it to our local machine’s localhost) as we do on our local machine when running a local web server. What we can do is expose it to a public URL using ngrok. Here comes the Python library flask-ngrok.

Follow the steps [here](https://medium.com/@kshitijvijay271199/flask-on-google-colab-f6525986797b) to get it running with `flask-ngrok`

Comment: Are you running any proxy server?

Comment: That command was for Linux distros to allow incoming connection on port 5000. Since you are using google colab, I will research on that and update in a minute

Comment: second also doesn't work, any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is working but i am not able to change my code according to this.Can you plz help in this?

Comment: Great. You don't need to change all the code, you only need flask-ngrok installed and have this line in your code `run_with_ngrok(app)`. This should work. If the answer has helped, then feel free to accept it as an answer, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: give me your email on vihalin123@newe-mail.com , this is my temp mail , i will message you with my orignal mail . Please i need help.

Comment: I have a chatbot code.This was test so i have to change complete code for my big file.Thanks .I accepted this as answer.:]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `output` library from Google colab like this:

```
from google.colab import output
output.serve_kernel_port_as_window(5000)
```

You will get a link `https://localhost:5000/` pointing to some address like `https://j92e7rh245-496ff2e9c6d22116-5000-colab.googleusercontent.com/` that's reachable from outside the notebook. You can view this link in a separate browser tab.

[image: run a web application on Google Colab]

See: [Browsing to servers executing on the kernel](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=6Ugsim80WVuq) (not sure why `serve_kernel_port_as_iframe` doesn't work).

#### Run Flask app in the background

In order to prevent one running cell from blocking the whole notebook, you need to run the server as a subprocess.

This is how I do it:

##### 1. save script to a file

```
%%writefile run_flask.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return ('Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

##### 2. run script in the background

```
import subprocess
with open('out.txt', "w") as stdout_file, open('err.txt', "w") as stderr_file:
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        "python run_flask.py",  # Your command here
        shell=True,
        stdout=stdout_file,
        stderr=stderr_file
    )
```

#### Viewing `localhost` from withing the notebook

Note that you can view the server running on `localhost` from within the Notebook, to see that just run in a cell the command

```
!curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this approach is that the flask server could be large. In essence, you would have to copy all of your notebook code into a single cell and then write out as script. Seems easier to simply save the notebook as a script on GitHub (say) and then !wget and run it. This should be attached to the answer that suggests using %%writefile.

Answer (score 0):

Before running your application just run below code:

`from google.colab.output import eval_js print(eval_js("google.colab.kernel.proxyPort(5000)"))`

I have also same problem, after using this its works for me.

Credit goes to blog author: https://deveshsurve.medium.com/running-flask-app-with-google-colab-c9f0c078fb53